# mergeMap with retryWhen running retry from the point it failed without starting all over again

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have N` urls I don't know how much ( until it's arrives stop condition )

Here is how I use it:

```
 from(observableUrls)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(url => callHttpService(url) , 4),
    retryWhen(
       // what is the algorithm or suggestion how to?
    )
  ).subscribe( result => {
     // doing some stuff with my results
  });
```

What is the algorithm or suggestion how to implement retry without running all over again if some of the URL's is failed.

***StackBlitz:***
https://angular-w5t15m.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `retryWhen` in the observable pipeline of individual `callHttpService(url)` like this:

```
from(observableUrls)
              .pipe(
                mergeMap(url => callHttpService(url)
                                    .pipe(
                                      retryWhen(
                                        // use your retryWhen logic here
                                      )
                                    ) , 4)                
              ).subscribe( result => {
                // doing some stuff with my results
              });
```

Having `retryWhen` in the observable pipeline of inner Observable (`callHttpService(url)`) will ensure to retry only that observable again as per `retryWhen` logic.
Hope it helps.